# Nil values passed after segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue that has been driving me crazy, i had my values working inside my main VC which is named ViewController for both Age and Gender, i tested this with print statement and it works, this is below

```
@IBAction func uploadBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NetworkServices.instance.getGender(image: imageView1.image!) { (gender) in
      self.Gender = gender
     // print(self.Gender!) // This prints a value
    }
    NetworkServices.instance.getAge(image: imageView1.image!) { (age) in
      self.Age = age
     // print(self.Age!) //This prints a value
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "updates", sender: self)
  }
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "updates" {
      let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
      destinationVC.userImage = image1
      destinationVC.genderFromUser = Gender
      destinationVC.ageFromUser = Age
    }
  }
```

but when i segue to another VC named SecondViewController which is below, i suddenly get an error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", i have created variables to hold my values which will come from the first VC but this first VC does not pass the values after seque, please help, i have checked stackoverflow and tried all solutions to no avail, i though this should be the easiest part, funny enough, my image successfully passes over from the first VC to second during seque. Please advice.

```
import UIKit
 import CLTypingLabel
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  var userImage: UIImage?
  var genderFromUser: String?
  var ageFromUser: Int?
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView2.image = userImage
    genderlabel.text = "Gender:"
    ageLabel.text = "Age:"
    print(ageFromUser!) // fatal error here
    print(genderFromUser!) // fatal error here
    print(userImage) // This is always successful
   // ageUser.text =
    // genderUser.text = userGender
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
  @IBOutlet weak var ageUser: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var genderUser: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var genderlabel: CLTypingLabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: CLTypingLabel!
}
```

My goal is to set labels to the values passed over from the first VC at the second VC.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order of operations. Your `NetworkServices.instance.get...` methods are *asynchronous*. I will use numbers to show you the order in which your code actually runs:

```
@IBAction func uploadBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    NetworkServices.instance.getGender(image: imageView1.image!) { (gender) in
      self.Gender = gender // 2 or 3
    }
    NetworkServices.instance.getAge(image: imageView1.image!) { (age) in
      self.Age = age // 3 or 2
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "updates", sender: self) // 1
}
```

So the segue is performed, and `prepare` is called, and the instance variables `genderFromUser` and `ageFromUser` are set, *before* you have set up your `self.Gender` and your `self.Age`. Therefore they are set to `nil`, because that's what they are at the time.

Later, of course, your asynchronous code comes along and *does* set `self.Gender` and `self.Age`, but it's too late; the train has left the station. SecondViewController already exists, and it has been configured with `nil` values.

Of course, since it *does* exist, you could *now* come along and set those instance properties *again* and get the SecondViewController to update its interface in response. Or you might work out some other solution. In general, this is a tricky problem — the problem of transitioning to another view controller at a time when its data is not ready yet and has to be fetched asynchronously.

[Also, you need to ask yourself, in fashioning a solution, what should happen if the data *never* arrives. What if the network chooses to go down at the exact moment the user taps the button? Welcome to the wild and wooly world of real life!]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i perfectly understand what the problem is now, this is my first app and i never though i will run into issues like this, in my head, this part should be the easiest and it turns out to be difficult,Now, i hope i can find a solution somewhere or think of one. what a rude awakening.